# Extracting repeating strings of data from Outlook to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to extract data from Outlook 2016 email body and filing to certain columns in Excel 2016.

I can extract the first occurrence of the data I want but if it appears multiple times in the email the data is not extracted.

I am very new at VBA and have been researching each stage of this process and trying to make the code fit my needs.  My emails come in a specific format as shown below:

> Company Name: ABC Company
>   GF Name and Number: General Foreman 1 xxx-xxx-xxxx
>   Number of Crews Working: 2
>   Circuits being Worked:
>
> Foreman Name and Number: Foreman 1 xxx-xxx-xxxx
>   Line Number:  Circuit 123456
>   Line Name / Point To Point
>   Structure: 1234 to 4567
>   Location Address:  1234 Main Street
>                                      Any City, State
>   Estimated Time:  7 am - 7:30 pm
>   Estimated Work Days: Tuesday - Thursday
>
> Foreman Name and Number: Foreman 2 xxx-xxx-xxxx
>   Line Number:  Circuit 987654
>   Line Name / Point To Point
>   Structure: 987 to 456
>   Location Address:  9876 Main Street
>                                      Any City, State
>   Estimated Time:  7 am - 7:30 pm
>   Estimated Work Days: Wednesday - Thursday

My intended output into Excel has the following columns: Line Number, Foreman, General Foreman, Crew Location Address, and time email was received.

Please see my code below:

```
Sub ValidateCrewLocations()

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim strBody As String
Dim strFind As String
Dim strColA, strColB, strColC, strColD, strColE As String
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim itm As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim firstterm As String
Dim secondterm As String
Dim startpos As Long
Dim stoppos As Long
Dim nextposition As Long
Dim strPublicFolder As String
Dim colFolders
Dim howManyInRange As Long
Dim foundCount As Long
Dim oFindRange As Range
Dim rngSearch As Range
Dim srchVal As String

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders).Folders("Crew Notifications")


nextposition = 1
i = 1

rCount = rCount + 1

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A6:E250").ClearContents

For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("From_Date").Value Then
srchVal = "Foreman Name and Number: "
strBody = OutlookMail.Body
howManyInRange = UBound(Split(strBody, srchVal))
Do
foundCount = foundCount + 1
strFind = "Line Number: "
strColA = Mid(strBody, InStr(1, strBody, strFind, 1) + Len(strFind))
strColA = Left(strColA, InStr(strColA, vbLf) - 1)
strFind = "Foreman Name and Number: "
strColB = Mid(strBody, InStr(1, strBody, strFind, 1) + Len(strFind))
strColB = Left(strColB, InStr(strColB, vbLf) - 15)
strFind = "GF Name and Number: "
strColC = Mid(strBody, InStr(1, strBody, strFind, 1) + Len(strFind))
strColC = Left(strColC, InStr(strColC, vbLf) - 15)
firstterm = "Location Address: "
secondterm = "Estimated Time:"
startpos = InStr(1, strBody, firstterm, vbTextCompare)
stoppos = InStr(startpos, strBody, secondterm, vbTextCompare)
strColD = Mid(strBody, startpos + Len(firstterm), stoppos - startpos - 
Len(secondterm) - 6)
strColE = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
Range("Job_Name").Offset(i, 0).Value = strColA
Range("Foreman").Offset(i, 0).Value = strColB
Range("General_Foreman").Offset(i, 0).Value = strColC
Range("Location_Address").Offset(i, 0).Value = strColD
Range("Email_Received_Time").Offset(i, 0).Value = strColE

i = i + 1

Loop While Not foundCount >= howManyInRange
End If

Next OutlookMail

Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

Dim c As Range
For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
With c
    .Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(.Value)
End With
Next c
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:15:00"), "ValidateCrewLocations"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could advance the starting point of the InStr search to new text blocks like this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ValidateCrewLocations()

Dim OutlookApp As outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder

Dim OutlookMail As Variant

Dim strBody As String
Dim strFind As String

Dim strColA As String
Dim strColB As String
Dim strColC As String
Dim strColD As String
Dim strColE As String

Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim itm As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim firstterm As String
Dim secondterm As String
Dim startpos As Long
Dim stoppos As Long

Dim strPublicFolder As String
Dim colFolders
Dim howManyInRange As Long
Dim foundCount As Long
Dim oFindRange As Range
Dim rngSearch As Range
Dim srchVal As String

Dim fbStart As Long

Set OutlookApp = New outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders).Folders("Crew Notifications")

'rCount = rCount + 1

'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A6:E250").ClearContents

For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items

    'If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("From_Date").Value Then

        strBody = OutlookMail.body
        srchVal = "Foreman Name and Number: "

        fbStart = 0

        howManyInRange = UBound(Split(strBody, srchVal))

        For i = 1 To howManyInRange

            strFind = "GF Name and Number: "
            strColC = Mid(strBody, InStr(1, strBody, strFind, 1) + Len(strFind))

            strColC = Left(strColC, InStr(strColC, vbLf) - 15)
            Debug.Print strColC

            strFind = "Foreman Name and Number: "

            'Foreman block start + 1
            ' On first instance of InStr the search starts at position 1
            ' On second and subsequent use of InStr,
            '  adding one to fbStart begins the search
            '  for the next Foreman block starting position
            '  one position past the beginning of the previous
            '  Foreman block starting position.
            fbStart = InStr(fbStart + 1, strBody, strFind, 1)
            Debug.Print i & " Foreman block start: " & fbStart

            strColB = Mid(strBody, InStr(fbStart, strBody, strFind, 1) + Len(strFind))
            'Debug.Print strColB

            strColB = Left(strColB, InStr(strColB, vbLf) - 15)
            Debug.Print strColB

            strFind = "Line Number: "

            strColA = Mid(strBody, InStr(fbStart, strBody, strFind, 1) + Len(strFind))
            'Debug.Print strColA

            strColA = Left(strColA, InStr(strColA, vbLf) - 1)
            Debug.Print strColA

            firstterm = "Location Address: "
            secondterm = "Estimated Time:"

            startpos = InStr(fbStart, strBody, firstterm, vbTextCompare)
            Debug.Print startpos

            stoppos = InStr(startpos, strBody, secondterm, vbTextCompare)
            Debug.Print stoppos

            strColD = Mid(strBody, startpos + Len(firstterm), stoppos - startpos - Len(secondterm) - 6)
            Debug.Print strColD

            strColE = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
            Debug.Print strColE

            'Range("Job_Name").Offset(i, 0).Value = strColA
            'Range("Foreman").Offset(i, 0).Value = strColB
            'Range("General_Foreman").Offset(i, 0).Value = strColC
            'Range("Location_Address").Offset(i, 0).Value = strColD
            'Range("Email_Received_Time").Offset(i, 0).Value = strColE

        Next

    'End If

Next OutlookMail

Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

'Dim c As Range
'For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
'With c
'    .Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(.Value)
'End With
'Next c
'Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:15:00"), "ValidateCrewLocations"

End Sub
```